# How do I write an if-statement that checks the index of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I have this method called setMonster(), in a class called 'AssetSetter' in a package called 'main', which creates new monsters based on information in another class from a different package called 'MON_GreenSlime'.

SetMonster() inside of the AssetSetter class looks like this(the list is much longer in reality but you get the jig):

```
public void setMonster(){

        gp.monster[0] = new MON_GreenSlime(gp);
        gp.monster[0].worldX = gp.tileSize * 26;
        gp.monster[0].worldY = gp.tileSize * 20;

        gp.monster[1] = new MON_GreenSlime(gp);
        gp.monster[1].worldX = gp.tileSize * 22;
        gp.monster[1].worldY = gp.tileSize * 18;

        gp.monster[2] = new MON_GreenSlime(gp);
        gp.monster[2].worldX = gp.tileSize * 24;
        gp.monster[2].worldY = gp.tileSize * 17;

    }
```

So inside of the MON_GreenSlime class I have a method called setAction() which sets AI movement to the monster. Inside this setAction() I want to make an if statement that checks the index of the gp.monster[] from the m as its condition. Something along the lines of this(if this would work)

```
if (gp.monster[index] index == 0){
  //do something
} 

else if (gp.monster[index] index == 1){
  //do something
}

//And so on... (The index is just as an example) Like I explained, I don't know how I would write such an if statement
```

The individual monsters AI movement is controlled by it's default x and y location, therefore when I create more than 1 monster I feel like I need some sort of if or switch statement to treat each array index individually.

Someone please let me know if you know of a simple solution :) I'm pretty new to Java, so go easy on me if its obvious

Comment: Objects don't know where they're referenced unless you tell them. Can you pass the index into the constructor?

Comment: Maybe it's just for the example, but you seem to have `index` already as a variable in your if statements. Couldn't just use this value?

Comment: Yes, it's just for example. I edited the question now. I don't know how I would write such an if statement... so...